# Android Studio Won't Open After Installing Plugins Supporting .csv Files

Tags: android-studio, plugins

I had imported a .csv file in Android Studio, which after opening suggested me to install plugins supporting *.csv files. After the installation, I have not been able to load the IDE. I get the splash-screen but the program is stuck.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the IDE, but the issue persists. Some solutions on stackoverflow suggest finding the CSV plugin folder and then deleting it, however, I cannot deduce which folder that is. I have also compared the plugins folder with a vanilla installation of AS on another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I had same problem. I solved it with removing plugins from folders listed bellow. To be honest I am livid that something like this can happen.

General solution:
I went to this pc and searched "csv". then I went throught list of all results and found that android studio plugins are stored in following folders:

- C:\Users\${user}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio${version}\plugins
- C:\Users\${user}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio${version}\plugins

First I removed just CSV folder, but that wasn't enough so I deleted also RanbowCSV and all folders which were created at time of first occurance of the problem. I think that should be enough, but I was angry so I deleted everything from those folders.

I also went to folder:

- C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins

There I searched "csv" and deleted found file "csv.py".

Hope that helps to anybody who gets baited to installing csv plugin as did I.

Comment: this worked perfectly, I deleted all folders in the path you mentioned and AS finally launched. Thanks!